# Conditional Validation for Serialized Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activerecord

How can I create a validation where `committed` presence needs to be true only if the challenge's category is `habit`?

```
class Challenge < ActiveRecord::Base
  CATEGORY = ['goal', 'habit']
  serialize :committed, Array
  validates :committed, presence: true, if: :habit # I also tried with 'habit' & 'Habit'
end
```

Comment: Where do you have the category stored at? Is it a column, or is in another table?

Comment: It's a column in challenge table, `t.string   "category"` @Nobita

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your category is called `'habit'` (note, it is not `'Habit'`), the validation would look as follows:

```
validates :committed, presence: true, if: ->(c) { c.category == 'habit' }
```

As a sidenote: I do not think your scopes will work, unless you have a column called `categories` in your `challenges` table.
Thus, if your intention was to select challenges, which have category `'habit'`, the scope would look as follows:

```
scope :habit, -> { where(category: 'habit') }
```

## EDIT

As per discussion in comments, if you want `committed` to be `nil` instead of `[""]` when nothing is there, add custom validation:

```
validate :committed_content

private

def committed_content
  self.committed = nil if committed.empty? || committed.all?(&:blank?)
  true
end
```

Comment: Ah good point. Yea I'll take that out since I thought it was part of it, but I guess not. I'm getting an error though, `syntax error, unexpected '.'
... true, if: ->(c) { c.category&.== 'habit' }`

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com Oh, may be you have Ruby <= 2.3. Try this: `validates :committed, presence: true, if: ->(c) { c.category == 'habit' }`

Comment: Been testing and I see the problem. I have this in the model `serialize :committed, Array` that I didn't include in the question :/ and so even if nothing is `:committed` I see it is passing in the database as `committed: [""]` instead of `nil`. You know I can make the validation work for this?

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com so you do no want to have `[""]` in the database and want to prevent it from being saved? If yes, you should add content validation. let me edit the question once you confirm

Comment: Yea either that... or make it `nil` when empty. Either way works if you know how. Thanks good sir!

Comment: Thanks again! It freezes up again. Do I need to add a `presence: true` anywhere? Is that meant in addition to `validates :committed, presence: true, if: ->(c) { c.category == 'habit' }`?

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com yea, this is additional check, which ensures, that you do not save empty array to db. So it's additional

Comment: Thanks so much for your patience on clarifying the root of the problem and getting to a solution :)

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com no problem, really glad you have it working! :)

Answer (score 2):

```
validates :committed, presence: true, :if => lambda { |c| c.category == 'Habit' }
```

Comment: That gives an error: `syntax error, unexpected => ...committed, presence: true, if => lambda { |c| c.categories ==... ... ^`

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com check now if is a symbol I have updated the answer

Comment: Thanks, but now I get `uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback::Habit`

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com Post your whole challenge.rb

Comment: Thanks for helping me narrow down the problem. It was a little more involved which Andrey helped figure out too.

Comment: even though you've just edited the answer, and no longer suggest to use non-existing table column `categories`, it is still wrong, because there is not such category as `"Habits"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a method and use it like this:

```
validates :committed, presence: true, if: :habit?

def habit?
  self.category == 'habit'
end
```